# How to start xterm in a directory containing .rvmrc file

Tags: rvm, zsh, xterm

Preface: I'm writing a [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) clone based for i3, and I'm a `zsh` user.

I want to open a xterm window (or any other terminal) in a given directory, where a .rvmrc file is present, and launch a (ruby-related) command.

Here an example scenario:

```
➜  /tmp  irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > 
➜  /tmp  cat r/.rvmrc 
rvm --create use 1.9.3@cloudflo-cfu
➜  /tmp  cd r  
Using /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392 with gemset cloudflo-cfu
➜  r  irb
1.9.3p392 :001 >
```

As you can see I'm using `2.0.0` as system ruby, and `1.9.3` in the `r/` direcotry.
I want, from some other place, launch an xterm window in that directory run `irb` and keep the terminal after that.

From a console I can do:

```
➜  /tmp  (cd /tmp/r && xterm -e "irb ; $SHELL ")&
```

This will work but the rvm load is done from the current terminal, and this trick cannot be done from a script:

```
➜  /tmp  cat test/start1.sh 
 (cd /tmp/r && xterm -e "irb ; $SHELL ")&
➜  /tmp  ./test/start1.sh
```

This will open irb in the `2.0.0` version.

So, how do I achieve this?

More in detail, what I'm trying to do is to spot the correct command message for i3-msg utility (that I'm using via [i3-py](https://github.com/ziberna/i3-py) binding uwing `i3.exec()`.

The result should do the following things:

- Start a terminal (`xterm` preferably)
- go to a given directory having rvm function loaded (or a workaround for the [cd wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6530020/258267) of rvm)
- launch a command (`irb` is fine for testing)
- launch `$SHELL` to prevent the terminal to be closed once exiting from `irb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command should do it:

```
( cd /tmp/r ; xterm -e $SHELL -l -c "irb ; $SHELL" )&
```

it will change to the directory, start `xterm` with running login(`-l`) shell(`$SHELL`) in it and asking it to execute(`-c`) `irb`

Comment: It was almost the only thing I didn't try. For i3 users, this works file but you need to put the command in a script and run i3-msg exec script.